# Function converted to arrow function - function not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm just learning ES6 and learned about arrow functions. I'm going through an existing file and converting functions one by one. I've converted numerous functions and all have worked as they did previously with the exception of 1.

Doing this, I can call `page` to get the current filename

```
let textArr = getPage.textArr;
let headingArr = getPage.headingArr;
const page = getPage.filename;

function getPage() {
  const url = window.location.pathname,
    fileWithExtension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    filename = fileWithExtension.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')    
  ;    
  if (filename == "foo") {
    textArr = [ 
      `Text`,
      `Text`
    ];
    headingArr = null;
    return {filename, textArr, headingArr}
  }
}
```

Leaving everything as is, converting to an arrow function, then calling `page` in console, I get:

> getPage is not defined at line 1

```
const getPage = () => {
        const url = window.location.pathname,
    fileWithExtension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    filename = fileWithExtension.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')    
  ;    
  if (filename == "foo") {
    textArr = [ 
      `Text`,
      `Text`
    ];
    headingArr = null;
    return {filename, textArr, headingArr}
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the balanced bracket. You are missing one closing bracket in the posted question.

Comment: `getPage` is a function, not a property. Call the function. `getPage.filename` is undefined (as per your first code block), while `getPage().filename` (probably) isn't.

Comment: While dealing with `arrow functions`, you have to define `getPage` first then call it. Otherwise it will throw error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hoisting problem. Functions are hoisted by default. That is not happening to arrow functions assigned to a variable. If you want that to work, you need to move the const definition before you call it. Like this:

```
const getPage = () => {
        const url = window.location.pathname,
    fileWithExtension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    filename = fileWithExtension.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')    
  ;    
  if (filename == "foo") {
    textArr = [ 
      `Text`,
      `Text`
    ];
    headingArr = null;
    return {filename, textArr, headingArr}
  }
}

let textArr = getPage().textArr;
let headingArr = getPage().headingArr;
const page = getPage().filename;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was told they were identical in nature other than syntax.

Comment: I'm able to call the function without a constructor as I'm doing (ie getPage.filename) and it works. I didn't notice that I neglected to include () in my code. Do you know why that works?

Comment: @froggomad who told you that ? arrow functions and functions have different scopes. It's a major difference.

Comment: I figured out why it works to call it without a constructor - it doesn't actually work... the function is overwriting the variable. Scope, scope, scope...

Comment: @froggomad: The problem you are experiencing is not specific to arrow functions. It would happen with a function expression (`const getPage = function() {}`) as well. Variables only get their value once the line with the assignment was executed.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually not calling your function, i.e. `const page = getPage.filename;` should be replaced by `const page = getPage().filename;`

For all three variables you could do something like:

```
let {textArr, headingArr, textArr} = getPage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add 1 more braces then it will work.

```
const getPage = () => {
    const url = window.location.pathname,
fileWithExtension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
filename = fileWithExtension.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');    
if (filename == "foo") {
   textArr = [ 
    `Text`,
    `Text`
   ];
   headingArr = null;
   return {filename, textArr, headingArr}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a typo in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem and you're using `jQuery` , remove the function definition from `$(document).ready()` function.

Regards